# How to extract specific line from large number (4.5 M) of files and debug properly?

Tags: python

I have a question regarding data manipulation and extraction.

I have a large amount of files (about 4.5 million files) from which I want to extract the third row (line) from each file and save it to a new file. However, there seems to be a small discrepancy of about 5 lines that are missing with the number of files and the number of lines extracted.

I have tried debugging to see where the error occurs. For debugging purposes  I can think of two possible problems: 
(1) I am counting the number of lines incorrectly (I have tried two algorithms for row count and they seem to match) 
(2) It reads an empty string which I have also tried to debug in the code. What other possibilities are there that I could look to debug?

Algorithm for calculating file length 1

```py
def file_len(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
        pass
    return i + 1
```

Algorithm for calculating file length 2

```py
def file_len2(filename):
    i = sum(1 for line in open(filename))
    return i
```

Algorithm for extracting line no. 3

```py
def extract_line(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i == 2: # Line number 3
            a = line
    if not a.strip():
        print(Error!)
    f.close()
    return a
```

There were no error messages. 
I expect the number of input files to match the number of lines in the output file, but there is a small discrepancy of about 5 lines out of 4.5 million lines between the two.

Comment: Are you sure all of the input files have a third line?  Maybe five of them are just short.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Wouldn't the code in my "extract_line" definition produce the error message that I have specified if that were the case? I have also tried the following within the code snippet: if a is None return print"Error"

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: If `a` is set globally, checking to see if there are less than three lines will fail.

(I would put this in comments but I don’t have enough rep)

Answer (score 0):

Your general idea is correct, but things can be made a bit simpler.

I also suppose that the discrepancy is due to files with empty third line, or with fewer than 3 lines..

```py
def extract_line(filename):
  with open(filename) as f:
    for line_no, line_text in enumerate(f):
    if line_no == 2:
      return line_text.strip()  # Stop searching, we found the third line
  # Here file f is closed because the `with` statement's scope ended.
  # None is implicitly returned here.

def process_files(source_of_filenames):
  processed = 0  # Count the files where we found the third line.
  for filename in source_of_filenames:
    third_line = extract_line(filename)
    if third_line:
      processed += 1  # Account for the success.
      # Write the third line; given as an illustration.
      with open(filename + ".3rd-line", "w") as f:
        f.write(third_line)
    else:
      print("File %s has a problem with third line" % filename);
  return processed

def main():  # I don't know the source of your file names.
  filenames = # Produce a list or a generator here.
  processed = process_files(filenames)
  print("Processed %d files successfully", processed)
```

Hope this helps.